# How to get ranges from numbers

Tags: r, statistics, range

I have a data frame table called "trips" from which I wanna create two new tables with new variables.

1. Existing data frame "trips" where I have the number of rides with particular trip duration in minutes:

| Trip duration (min) | Number of rides |
| --- | --- |
| 0,5 | 50 |
| 1 | 300 |
| 3 | 500 |
| 14 | 200 |
| 5 | 100 |
| 6 | 50 |
| 1 | 50 |
| 9 | 50 |
| etc | etc |

2. I want to create a new data frame and add *1st column with ranges(bins) for trip duration*:

| Range for Trip duration | Trip duration (min) | Number of rides |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0-1 | 0,5 | 50 |
| 0-1 | 1 | 300 |
| 2-3 | 3 | 500 |
| 8-15 | 14 | 200 |
| 4-7 | 5 | 100 |
| 4-7 | 6 | 50 |
| 0-1 | 1 | 50 |
| 8-15 | 9 | 50 |
| etc | etc | etc |

3. I want to create a new dataframe in which there will be 2 columns: *1) Ranges(bins) for Trip duration from previous table, 2) Sum of number of rides per each range:*

| Range for trip duration | Sum of number of rides |
| --- | --- |
| 0-1 | 400 |
| 2-3 | 500 |
| 4-7 | 150 |
| 8-15 | 250 |
| etc | etc |

4. Additional question.

Should I create the ranges for duration by myself: "0-1", "2-3"... or there is a solution how to create ranges for groups of numbers automatically? In my existing table there are trip durations until 1000 min but I see that 80% of rides are accumulated in range 0-15 min.

I found on this platform how to add column with ranges for one variable(one column of numbers) but I don't know how to solve my issue in total - to create ranges for 1 variable (trip duaration) and then calculate in another column 2 variable (number of rides) per range of trip duration.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a base R function `cut` which you can use to make the bins.
Unfortunately your data is a bit sparse. The following uses therefor an artificial DF with 100 rows:

```r
set.seed(123)
# make vector with duration between 0 and 30
duration <- ceiling(runif(100, 0, 30))

# make vector with number of rides (between 50 and 500)
no_rides <- floor(runif(100, 50, 500))

# !! cut the duration into 10 bins
range <- cut(duration, breaks = 10)

# make DF
df <- data.frame(duration, range, no_rides)
head(df)
#>   duration       range no_rides
#> 1        9   (6.8,9.7]      319
#> 2       24 (21.3,24.2]      199
#> 3       13 (12.6,15.5]      269
#> 4       27 (24.2,27.1]      479
#> 5       29   (27.1,30]      267
#> 6        2 (0.971,3.9]      450

# claclulate sum of no_rides for each bin
aggregate(
  no_rides ~ range,
  data = df,
  FUN = sum
)
#>          range no_rides
#> 1  (0.971,3.9]     2584
#> 2    (3.9,6.8]     3489
#> 3    (6.8,9.7]     2894
#> 4   (9.7,12.6]     3049
#> 5  (12.6,15.5]     3122
#> 6  (15.5,18.4]     1786
#> 7  (18.4,21.3]     2434
#> 8  (21.3,24.2]     3270
#> 9  (24.2,27.1]     3391
#> 10   (27.1,30]     2065
```